# Error in sample.int() triggered by clinicalFeatures argument in maftools's oncoplot function

Tags: r

I'm using the maftools R package to visualise large MAF files. I've been running into the following error when trying to create an oncoplot:

Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

When this occurs the oncoplot is generated, but without legends, annotations or a title. This only happens when I try to use annotations with large number of categories (e.g. if I select 'Case' as clinicalfeature annotation and there are >100 different possible Case IDs). The same large dataset is displayed without issues when a simpler category is used as classifying feature.

I've tried using different Mafs as input and/or different clinical data. Tests suggest the source of the issue is the large number of groups in some categories. I think possibly the oncoplot function is unable to process that many category groups, although I'm unsure how the oncoplot function is relying on sample.int() here. It occurs to me it could be an issue with generating a large legend for such a complex annotation but there doesnt seem a way to turn off legends.